# Empty Map When It send via a rest web-service

Tags: java, rest, web-services

I have a simple Object which contain a String and a `Map<String, Object>` defined like this :

My Object

```
@XmlRootElement
public class WebServicePatternObject {

    private @Getter @Setter String code;
    private @Getter @Setter Map<String, Object> fieldsMap = new HashMap<>();

    public WebServicePatternObject() {
    }

    public WebServicePatternObject(String code, Map<String, Object> fieldsMap) {
        this.code = code;
        this.fieldsMap = fieldsMap;
    }
}
```

Client side

```
public String getResult(String paramValues, Map<String, Object> mapFieldsValues) 
         throws Exception {
    try {
        Client client = Client.create();

        String uriTarget = 
                   "http://10.6.6.6:8080/admin/ressources-ws-rest/patterns/lastSequence";
        WebServicePatternObject wspo = 
                                new WebServicePatternObject(paramValues, mapFieldsValues);
        WebResource webResource = client.resource(uriTarget);

        //{"code":"CODE_PA","fieldsMap":{"code_1":123456,"code_2":"abcd"}}
        System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(wspo));

        ClientResponse response = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .post(ClientResponse.class, new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(wspo));

        if (response.getStatus() != 201) {
            throw new Exception("Exception Occured - HTTP Error Code :" 
                                 + response.getStatus());
        }

        String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
        //This return SUCCESS_RESULT
        System.out.println(output);
        return output;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new Exception("Something wrong!");
    }
}
```

Service side

```
@Path("/patterns")
public class PatternsWebService {

    @POST
    @Path("/lastSequence")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getLastSequence(WebServicePatternObject wspo) {
        //WebServicePatternObject{code=CODE_PA, fieldsMapAP={}} <<----------Empty Map, Why?
        System.out.println(wspo);
        return Response.status(201)
                .entity("SUCCESS_RESULT")
                .build();
    }
}
```

---

When I call `getResult(String paramValues, Map<String, Object> mapFieldsValues)` with :

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("code_1", 123456);
map.put("code_2", "abcd");
getResult("CODE_PA", map);
```

The service response is `SUCCESS_RESULT` but the Map in the service is empty `fieldsMapAP={}`

My question is, why the String is send successfully but the Map is empty, I think I miss something in my code, any idea please?

Comment: Have you tried to post the `WebServicePatternObject` object to your endpoint without converting it to a JSON String manually? That is simply `webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, wspo);`

Comment: Thank you @dpr, it show me an error `com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class com.webservices.WebServicePatternObject, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found`

Comment: Do you have the `jersey-media-json-jackson` module on your application's classpath?

Comment: @dpr I have `com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:1.19` should I need to add https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json-jackson/2.25.1 to my classpath on both sides ?

Comment: For Jersey 1.19 it's probably https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-json/1.19

Comment: Thank you @dpr I will let you know if it work

Comment: @dpr the precedent error is not show, but the Map still empty!!

Comment: Maybe try to make it a `Map<String, String>` not sure if `Object` is handled like expected.

Comment: I'm sorry @dpr the same empty map :(

Comment: @YCF_L Your code is working correct. I have tried it and catched the Map is full.

Comment: I'm wondering why you wrote `fieldsMapAP={}`, as the field in the `WebServicePatternObject` class is called `fieldMap` (without the `AP` suffix). Is this just a typo?

Comment: @dpr it is not a typo, it is toString which print this `@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "WebServicePatternObject{" + "code=" + code + ", fieldsMapAP=" + fieldsMapAP + '}';
    }`

Comment: But the field is called `fieldsMap` and not `fieldsMapAP` according to your first code snippet.

Comment: @dpr yes now it is a typo, `fieldsMapAP` is the correct name, i think i should to rename it in my code, sorry

Comment: Maybe you could try to print the JSON string in the service endpoint as well instead of using the `toString` method. Just to avoid any misunderstandings.

Comment: If you renamed the field at some point, but you're still using the old version on the client side, this would explain the observed behaviour.

Comment: Thank you @dpr let me take deep breath, I will let you know I really appreciate your help

Comment: thank you @dpr finally I solved my problem, you can check my solution above, i really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> added as an answer of the comment. It may be the answer of the question

*added as a answer because dunno how to insert image on comment*

I would prefer share you a clean  maven repository but i was working with a plug-in project. The project also have grizzly web server and gson like that. You can pick over what you need inside of them. I am sure that your problem about version of jackson.

```
    aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0-b30
    grizzly-framework-2.3.28
    grizzly-http-2.3.28 
    grizzly-http-server-2.3.28 
    hk2-api-2.5.0-b30
    hk2-locator-2.5.0-b30 
    hk2-utils-2.5.0-b30 
    jackson-annotations-2.5.4
    jackson-core-2.5.4 
    jackson-databind-2.5.4 
    jackson-jaxrs-base-2.5.4
    jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.5.4
    jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.5.4 
    javassist-3.20.0-GA
    javax.annotation-api-1.2 
    javax.inject-2.5.0-b30 
    javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1
    jersey-client-2.25 
    jersey-common-2.25
    jersey-container-grizzly2-http-2.25 
    jersey-entity-filtering-2.20
    jersey-guava-2.25
    jersey-media-jaxb-2.25
    jersey-media-json-jackson-2.20 
    jersey-server-2.25
    osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1
    validation-api-1.1.0.Final
```

**server side dependencies**

[image: Server Side dependencies]

**client side dependencies**

[image: Client Side dependencies]

Comment: sorry for the late anwer. @YCF_L I just added the server side dependencies. client side that i have :  Jersey-bundle-1.14 --- jersey-multipart-1.14--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core ---jackson-databind-2.14 --- jackson-anotations-2.14 --- jackson-core-2.14